# Pvlib: Problem with DatetimeIndex of ModelChain

Tags: pandas, python-datetime, pvlib

I am struggling with forwarding the time series to the ModelChain.

The Code looks like that:

---

```
import pandas as pd
import pvlib
from pvlib.pvsystem import PVSystem
from pvlib.location import Location
from pvlib.modelchain import ModelChain
from pvlib.temperature import TEMPERATURE_MODEL_PARAMETERS
temperature_model_parameters = TEMPERATURE_MODEL_PARAMETERS['sapm']['open_rack_glass_glass']
CEC_modules = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('CECMod')
cec_inverters = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('cecinverter')
CEC_module = CEC_modules['SunPower_SPR_E20_327_COM']
cec_inverter = cec_inverters['Fronius_International_GmbH__Fronius_Symo_10_0_3_208_240__240V_']
location = Location(latitude=14.35, longitude=47.97, altitude=300,
                    name='xy',)
system = PVSystem(surface_tilt=20, surface_azimuth=160,
                 ....)
mc = ModelChain(system, location, .....,
                spectral_model='no_loss', #spectral model 'no loss' otherwise error
                temperature_model='sapm', losses_model='no_loss')
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['Time'], sep=";",)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
Timeseries = df['Time']
print(Timeseries)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
print(type(Timeseries))
weather = pd.DataFrame([df['Irradiation Horizontal (W/m2) 15min avg.'],
                        df['Irradiation Diffuse (W/m2) 15min avg.'],
                        df['Direct Normal Irradiation (W/m²) 15 min avg.'],
                        df['Temperature Ambient (C)'],
                        df['Wind Speed (Meteo) (m/s)']],                    
                        columns=['ghi', 'dhi', 'dni', 'temp_air', 'wind_speed'],
                        index=[pd.DatetimeIndex(Timeseries, tz='Europe/Vienna')])       
#forwarding the dates from the excel data doesn't work
mc.run_model(weather);
```

---

Spyder (Python 3.7) shows this error:

```
0    2020-01-23 07:30:00
1    2020-01-23 07:45:00
......
36   2020-01-23 16:30:00
37   2020-01-23 16:45:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Time                                            datetime64[ns]
Irradiation Horizontal (W/m2) 15min avg.                object
Irradiation Diffuse (W/m2) 15min avg.                   object
Direct Normal Irradiation (W/m²) 15 min avg.            object
Temperature Ambient (C)                                 object
Wind Speed (Meteo) (m/s)                                object
dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-157-e72efaf102a2>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/maki4/Python/files/timestamp problem.py', wdir='C:/Users/maki4/Python/files')

  File "C:\Users\maki4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\maki4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/maki4/Python/files/timestamp problem.py", line 59, in <module>
    index=[pd.DatetimeIndex(Timeseries, tz='Europe/Vienna')])

  File "C:\Users\maki4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 462, in __init__
    mgr = arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\maki4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 87, in arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)

  File "C:\Users\maki4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1699, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)

  File "C:\Users\maki4\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1719, in construction_error
    "Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(passed, implied)

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 5), indices imply (38, 5)
```

---

The error looks like there is something wrong with the format of the table...

I would be very grateful for any help or recommendation to fix the problem.

Kind regards
Markus

loremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsum

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be overly complicated. Why recreate the 'df' dataframe as 'weather' instead of renaming the columns?  The brackets here 'index=[pd.DatetimeIndex(Timeseries, tz='Europe/Vienna')]' are not needed but I can't tell if that would resolve the issue.